# Download youtube videos in android

Tags: android

I want to download videos from you tube in android by programmatically..Still now i can able to stream these you tube videos.I searched in Internet..But there is no perfect solution for me..Please suggest that possible solutions for that issue..Thanks

Comment: Please give me that some idea regards to that issue

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? Have you tried to do some research regarding this issue? Show us some code. Stackoverflow isn't a place for asking people to code your application **for** you.

Comment: Pretty sure this is against YouTube's TOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537202/play-high-quality-youtube-videos-using-videoview#comment19679509_13537202) out. I use this function to extract the direct download links from a youtube video (it returns an array with links). All you need to do is to get the html code of the video (not the mobile version!) using this:

```
                 // url = youtube link (e.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ)
  public String DownloadText(String url) throws IOException{
      String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1)";
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, userAgent);

      HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

      String html = "";
      InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
      String line = null;
      while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      {
          str.append(line);
      }
      in.close();
      html = str.toString();

      return html;
    }
```

Comment: Which tag should i use to download the video?
I mean in which tag i can find the direct download url?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no tag that holds the direct link. The flash object holds all of the needed parameters, and you need to extract them and reproduce the direct link.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I got it. I needed to create the new link from the different tags. Finally, i have make it

Comment: @MiteshShah can you pls help me to do same.

Comment: @MiteshShah Bro, i am also in need of help to find direct link to download with download manager from youtube link, please please help me all of you guys